# Best approach to address interchangeable use of tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Both [preloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preloading) and [preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preload) tags pretty much used interchangeably across StackOverflow.

The [preloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preloading) tag currently holds 238 questions whiles the [preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preload) one holds 718.

What should be the appropriate action for such situations?

Is it re-tagging or simply the creation of a synonym tag?

Would love to learn and appreciate your inputs for future scenarios.

Comment: Ok, really, what kind of topic is preloading? Preloading a module, firmware, image, file, etc.?

Comment: @Braiam: basically, I will define it as holding or storing a resource into a state for future use. Mainly, for performance optimisation.

Comment: Which can be done in thousands separate ways. This is not a programming problem, it's a solution. We aren't supposed to create tags for stuff people can answer, but if the answer is already know, what they are going to do?

Comment: If we are going to deal with a "problem", lets solve it in a way that down the road we don't have to touch it again. If there's a problem with [preload*], synonyms isn't a solution.

Comment: @Braiam: Kindly rephrase please; I'm having a challenge getting the point you are trying make. What is your suggested solution? Do you mind explaining so I could learn from you for similar situations?

Comment: This tag shouldn't even exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192173/discussion-between-nyedidikeke-and-braiam).