# Handling [preload] and [preloading] tags

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I came across [this meta question about `preload` and `preloading` tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383071/best-approach-to-address-interchangeable-use-of-tags), and it seems the consensus from the comments and the linked chat room is that the [preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preload) and [preloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preloading) tags should be removed.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Preloading is a generic term, and elaboration in the question is required for it to make sense. For example, the question could describe loading files into an I/O cache, requesting web pages ahead of time, or a host of other things. As it stands, the preload tags itself doesn't carry enough meaning to stand on its own.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

While preloading is programming specific, it is vague, as described above.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Preloading is too broad to carry meaning by itself (as per answer to question 1).

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Preloading does not necessarily have the same meaning in all contexts. It could refer to I/O caching, preloading HTTP pages into caches, or other meanings. Thus, the tag is ambiguous without additional contexts.

The tag could possibly be replaced with [prefetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prefetch) where applicable, but at the very least one of these tags should be made a synonym of the other. I am not making a burnination request yet in order to get a wider community consensus first on what the appropriate course of action is here.

Comment: In my opinion, I would make preloading a synonym of preload.

Comment: @JL2210 What questions you expect to be on topic and using these tags?

Comment: @Braiam Probably questions about loading data into memory early for future use. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @JL2210 That's called read() in most languages. We don't need a tag for reading.

Comment: @Braiam There are languages with [specific mechanisms for preloading data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content). Perhaps some research into the issue is warranted?

Comment: @HereticMonkey then create tags for those specific mechanisms. Tags are supposed to be about concrete and unambiguous topics. If the language you are using change radically the question, then obviously it isn't concrete or unambiguous.

Comment: @Braiam The mechanism is called "preload". You said, "We don't need a tag for reading", claiming that preloading is the same as reading. My comment was specifically hinting to you (perhaps too subtly) that maybe you should consider not making broad sweeping generalizations without doing research about the subject first.

Comment: I was just suggesting to make the 'preloading' tag a synonym of 'preload'. Let's not get into an argument, now.

Comment: @JL2210that ship sailed before https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383071/best-approach-to-address-interchangeable-use-of-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: For the record this is the meta question I linked to at the beginning of my post.